# Display a set value from a mysqli_query in Select list

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a form that captures username and type (controls what the user has access to), and writes it to the database.  The type is controlled by a select box.  Presently there are only three values possible: 1, 4 and 5.

```
<?php

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `usertype` ORDER BY `id`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username">
        </li>
        <li>
            User Type:<br>
            <select name="type">
            <?php
                while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $data1['id'] . '">' . $data1['type'] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

I have another page on which I want to retrieve a single existing user so that their username or type can be changed.  The problem I'm having is with the select box.  It's not showing what is in the database. For the particular user I'm testing with, the select box should be showing a type of 4.  Instead it is showing a type of 5.  Code of the second page is below.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<?php
$user_id = 47;

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `usertype` ORDER BY `id`";
$result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);

$sql2 =
"SELECT *
FROM `users`
WHERE `users`.user_id = $user_id";

$result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
$user_details = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
print_r_html($user_details);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user_details['username'];?>">
        </li>

        <li>
            <select name="type">
            <?php
                while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
                {
                    echo '<option value="' . $data1['id'] . '" success="' . $user_details['type'] . '">' . $data1['type'] . '</option>';
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Here is the array dumb of $user_details:

```
Array
(
    [user_id] => 47
    [username] => paul
    [password] => 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
    [first_name] => Paul
    [last_name] => Smith
    [email] => paul@somewhere.com
    [email_code] => dda1f2a2c5b29f3b28827716c2dffe61
    [active] => 1
    [password_recover] => 0
    [type] => 4
    [allow_email] => 1
    [profile] => images/profile/6dc76117b3.jpg
    [acct_nbr] => XXXXXXXXX (intentionally masked)
)
```

The select list does have all the values in it, just the wrong one is displaying as selected.

p.s. I know I don't have a submit button in the form yet.

Thanks.

Comment: The HTML syntax to select an option is [`selected="selected"`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/option/selected). You'll need to use some PHP logic to compare `$userdetails['type']` with `$data1['type']` and output `selected="selected"` if they match.

Comment: Your first body of code, you're not selecting `id`, so it won't show. You're only selecting the `type` column. Same thing for `username` in the 2nd body of code.

Comment: *...in other words,* choose (all) the columns you wish to query and to echo out.

Comment: Fred -- Good catch on the id vs. type.  This is a done up example, simplified to not have to include all of the joins in the real code.  I was trying to keep it concise.  In the real code it is all referenced by id.  Anyway, not the issue in this case.  The issue is how to select the correct set value in the select box.

Comment: @showdev -- Thanks for that.  I think you are pointing me in the right direction.  Can you elaborate?  Are you suggesting putting an if statement in the option tag to say selected="selected" when the value equals what is stored in the database?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Looks like others have answered similarly. Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to showdev for pointing me in the right direction.  The code below accomplished what I needed.  It replaces the form in the second block of code posted in the question.

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Username:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user_details['username'];?>">
        </li>

        <li>
            <select name="type">
            <?php
                while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
                {
                    if ($data1['id'] == $user_details['type']) {
                        echo '<option value="' . $data1['id'] . '" selected="selected">' . $data1['type'] . '</option>';
                    } else {
                        echo '<option value="' . $data1['id'] . '">' . $data1['type'] . '</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
            </select>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this. You want to check if the user type = to the data type. Not sure what the 'success=' is.

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Username:<br>
                <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $user_details['username'];?>">
            </li>

            <li>
                <select name="type">
                <?php
                    while ($data1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))
                    {
                        $selected = ($user_details['type'] == $data1['type']) ? 'selected="selected"' : false;
                        echo '<option value="' . $data1['id'] . '" '.$selected.'>' . $data1['type'] . '</option>';
                    }
                ?>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
```